# Github no me permite hacer push

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Hace poco que estoy usando github y hasta ahora ya me había acostumbrado a que cada vez que quisiera subir nuevos archivos o cambios de los archivos a mi repositorio,  simplemente bastaba con meter todo dentro de un directorio, luego poner:

```
-git add *
-git commit -m "modificaciones, cosas nuevas, etc.."
-git push
```

Y listo, así me funcionaba siempre. Sin embargo ahora, no puedo. Al hacer el commit me sale con

> changes not staged for commit

y me marca justo el directorio que quiero subir. Y al hacer el push me dice

> Fatal:the current branch has no upstream branch

No entiendo qué pasó, ¿por qué dejó de funcionar si antes andaba tan bien?

Comment: Que resultados te lanza el git status?

Comment: Esto:

http://pastebin.com/m9RvfmZa

Comment: Intenta con git add . desde el work directory, para añadir el archivo que tal ves eliminaste o usa git rm --cached con el nombre del archivo para deshacer los archivos que eliminaste y git no los untracked (siga), luego intenta hacer git commit -m "mensaje", quedo atento....

Comment: Lo hice

http://pastebin.com/kQ5sNFcd

Luego

http://pastebin.com/ikxkzc5L

Y sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: Ahora borré el repositorio desde github, lo creé de nuevo, lo cloné en la línea de comandos e hice todo de nuevo, pero sigo teniendo los mismos problemas.

http://pastebin.com/WvjgPf5U

Comment: puedo entrar a tu github y clonarlo para subir algo como prueba?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44489/discussion-between-julian-salas-and-felipe-pino).

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al `Pastebin`(Ps) que mostraste verifica si está apuntando a tu `git hub` con:

```
git remote --v
```

Si clonaste tu repositorio debes tener algo como esto:

```
origin  https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter.git (push)
```

En tu `Ps` tienes un error, debes especificar tu URL o configurar el repositorio remoto, para ello puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter.git
```

Luego ya puedes realizar tus `push` con:

```
git push <name>
```

Para este caso `name` sería `origin`.

Verifica la documentación de `git` en español es buena:

[Fundamentos de Git - Trabajando con repositorios remotos.](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Trabajando-con-repositorios-remotos)

Comment: Me sigue molestando con lo mismo:

http://pastebin.com/YPVxp2us

Comment: Intenta update tu repositorio local con el remoto con git pull, luego vuelve a intentarlo

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DjDksT62 Más errores.

Comment: Probé lo que sale acá:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge

git config --global push.default current

Y

git push --force 

Y ahí subió los archivos. El problema es que ahora hago push, no me da ningún error pero en realidad no sube nada.

¿Por qué se puso tan imbécil esta aplicación? estaba funcionando perfecto hasta hace poco. He perdido todo un día de trabajo por culpa de sus errores raros.

Comment: @FelipePino primero revisa el git status, luego si está bien, intenta con esto  git pull -f https:["tu repo"] . Luego verifica en que rama estás debes estár en master, git checkout, ya después puedes hacer push con esto
git push -f https:["tu repo"].

Comment: Hice todo eso y ya no tengo errores, cuando hago push me dice que "everything is up to date", pero realmente no actualiza nada, porque modifiqué un archivo, le puse un "HOLA" por ahí y no me sale el HOLA.

Comment: Tuve que hacer lo que sale aquí:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704480/why-does-git-commit-not-save-my-changes

git commit -am "mensaje"

Con eso recién me funcionó.

Comment: Ya, se solucionó el problema. De ahora en adelante todos mis commits tienen que ser con -am o no funciona, los archivos se me quedan en "untracked files".

Comment: @FelipePino si solucionaste el problema te aconsejo por favor que actualices tu pregunta con la respuesta o pongas la respuesta a la solución del problema.

Comment: lo que haces con git commit -am "mensaje" es hacer el commint y añadir los files al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Vuelvo a tener el mismo problema hoy.

Cuando hago commit me sale en "untracked files" los archivos donde hice las modificaciones siempre, y ahora el git commit -am no funciona. Me tiene harto git.

Comment: De nuevo la misma mierda, estoy teniendo otra vez los mismos errores de arriba. ¿Por qué la porquería no me deja subir los archivos y ya? ¿por qué me tiene que estar molestando y haciéndome perder tiempo? me tiene frustrado esta cochinada de git, es una mierda.

Comment: Si no pegas los mensajes de error no podemos ayudarte.